# What is this design style called?

Tags: style-identification

I'd like to know what this design style is called. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Hi Zooey! Is it possible to show what results you got from your research so far and what you tried to find out the style of this illustration? Maybe post more examples too.

Comment: It's an illustration. Reminiscent of 50s/60s, block prints, but no real particular name for this style.

Comment: we absolutely need more examples..

Answer (score 2):

This image is a still from a video done for Eco Justice Canada by the firm Giant Ant: https://vimeo.com/53447230

While the video is new, the imagery and animation style used is heavily influenced by mid-century graphic design (tear-drop and other simple shapes, limited color palette, rough ink textures, the type of animated transitions used). Googling "[mid-century graphic design](https://www.google.com/search?q=mid-century%20animation&es_sm=91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIwaLDnpDGxwIVRzOICh3_1A5k&biw=1284&bih=734#tbm=isch&q=mid-century%20graphic%20design%22mid-century%20graphic%20design%22)" or "[mid-century animation](https://www.google.com/search?q=mid-century%20animation&es_sm=91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIwaLDnpDGxwIVRzOICh3_1A5k&biw=1284&bih=734%22mid-century%20animation%22)" will give you some nice examples of work from this period.

Comment: "Modernism". That is the trem we called over the mid century artwoks, including printing ads, furnitures design and Architecture.